Looking for 3rd party API for ACTIVITY_SPL_TRANSFER
I'm a Junior Dev and Senior/Direct Prod Mgr. I'm building signaldancer.com, a DeFi app.
One of the features we are building is a pump-dot-fun Raydium deployment watcher. Basically once the raydium pool is seeded, I want to watch those tokens, and then watch the growth of holders over time.
I found the solscan URL to watch these activities at https://solscan.io/account/39azUYFWPz3VHgKCf3VChUwbpURdCHRxjWVowf5jUJjg?activity_type=ACTIVITY_SPL_TRANSFER&remove_spam=true&flow=out&to_address=5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1&exclude_token=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112#transfers
I am now trying to duplicate the table at the bottom of the above page in my app.
I tried using helius, but I'm not sure it can do what I need. Helius suggests using this endpoint: https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history
What I'm seeking:

free, or low-cost 3rd party API services where I can find the data I'm looking for
sponsorship or grants from Solana possibly

Thanks

You can use Pump Portal API for Raydium and Pump.fun. Uses HTTPS endpoints,  allowing you to programmatically trade on, and gather data from, the Pump.fun bonding curve & Raydium LPs.
https://pumpportal.fun/ or
https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/category/solana/
usually they will charge transaction fees around 0.5%.
If you need help in development for pumpfun, let's me know.
